# Simple application of Phragmen Lindelof

Tags: complex-analysis, analytic-number-theory

I refer to the paper Goldfeld, D.; Sarnak, P. Sums of Kloosterman sums. Invent. Math. 71 (1983), no. 2, 243--250. They study the usual Kloosterman zeta function $Z_{m,n}(s,\chi)$, whose precise definition is not important here. Using the estimate
$$
|Z_{m,n}(s,\chi)|= O\Big(\frac{|s|^{1/2}}{\sigma-1/2}\Big), \qquad s=\sigma + it, \sigma>\frac12,
$$
they claim that as an application of the Phragmen-Lindelöf, for any $\epsilon>0$, we have
$$
\Big|Z_{m,n}\Big(\frac{1+s}{2},\chi\Big)\Big| \ll |t|^{\frac12-\frac{\sigma}{2\beta}+\epsilon},\qquad 0<\epsilon \le \sigma\le \beta +\epsilon.
$$
The Phragmen-Lindelöf principle is the following: Let $f(s)$ be a regular function of finite order in $\beta_1\le \sigma\le\beta_2$, and $f(s) = O(|t|^{k_i})$ for $\sigma=\beta_i$, with $i=1,2$. Then
$$
f(s) = O(|t|^{k(\sigma)})
$$
uniformly for $\beta_1\le \sigma\le\beta_2$, where $k(x)$ is the linear function such that $k(\beta_1) = k_1$ and $k(\beta_2)=k_2$.

Question: How do I express the first big-$O$ estimate in the shape $O(|t|^{k})$? Presumably it is because of this that I am not able to see what how function $k(\sigma)$ in this case should be derived.

Comment: mm, maybe you need a functional equation for $Z_{m,n}(s)$?  the first estimate is for $\sigma >1/2$ and the second for $\sigma >0$.  i think it's possible that that's the important bit and not the phragmen-lindeloef principle, but not sure

Comment: @tomos I had wondered this too, but in the paper they make no mention of a functional equation (let alone prove/cite it). Indeed, the authors explicitly say in Sect. 3 (paraphrased) that by the big-O estimate and the Phragmen Lindelöf Principle, the upper bound follows..

Comment: You just need to know that $Z$ is bounded when $\sigma = \beta + \varepsilon$, which follows from the definition of $\beta$. So you have the bound $Z(s) \ll_{\varepsilon} |t|^{1/2}$ for $\sigma = 1/2 + \varepsilon$ and $Z(s) \ll_{\varepsilon} 1$ for $\sigma = 1 + \varepsilon$. Now apply Phragmen-Lindeloef.

Comment: Thanks @PeterHumphries! I don't immediately see how to get those bounds or how they give the final estimate, to be honest, so I'll sleep on it :) I don't doubt you're right though!